# When item is hovered toggle 2 div id's, item click 2 div id stays

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle

I have a very frustrating situation, that should be seemingly simple.

Whem item (.item-2) is hovered I now have 2 div id that toggles (#text_2, text_2-2). Then when item is clicked, I want both #text_2 and #text_2-2 to "stay" meaning being visible until either of them is clicked.

I have found a script, that works but only #text_2-2 stay when item-2 is clicked.

Both id has been assigned the class "hide-default", but this is a class that's assigned for every other id's in the script also , and is quite entangled with another JavaScript function.

Also the items have been assigned a data-target id's #text_2, #text_3, #text_4 etc. Which I guess could be the reason, that I want to make them stay, the way I want.

Can anybody tell what to do and perhaps explain, why it is being so tricky and possibly how the data-target effects how it works in JavaScript?

Comment: Programming is not about copy-pasting code all over the place. Don't worry, It's a common beginner mistake. You should reason about class selectors, use them. Keep to the DRY principles. You need only one function, not 21 or *N* copies of the same. What was your issue? I'm lost in the huge load of code and unworking fiddle example.

Comment: Multiple `id="Image"`- that's not allowed. ID should be **unique**

Comment: Don't use `&nbsp;` for styling purpose. use CSS instead.

Comment: Hey Roko C. Buljan. My question was how to have have both #text_2 and #text_2-2 toggle, accroding to the javascript code. At this point in time when .item-2 is hoveres both id show, but only #text_2-2 stays on click.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplification of your code:

```js
jQuery($ => {  // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  $(".item[data-target]").on({
      mouseenter() {
        if (!this._active) $(this.dataset.target).removeClass('hidden');
      },
      mouseleave() {
        if (!this._active) $(this.dataset.target).addClass('hidden');
      },
      click() {
        this._active = !this._active; // Toggle 
        $(this.dataset.target).removeClass('hidden');
      }
    });

});
```

```css
.items { display: flex; cursor: pointer; }
.hidden { display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item" data-target="#text_2">
    <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/2e8" alt="Some image 1" width="60">
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-target="#text_3">
    <img src="//placehold.it/60x60/f69" alt="Some image 2" width="60">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="hidden" id="text_2" style="color:#2e8;">Textile design</div>
  <div class="hidden" id="text_3" style="color:#f69;">Objects</div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Roko C. Buljan. This looks good, trying it right now. HOwever in my current code theres two div id's connected to each item, #text_2 and #text_2-2. I was interested in how I should incorporate both in the javascript.

Comment: This is where I got really stuck earlier, and what I am really tager to understand.

Comment: @CarinaThornval instead of using IDs you could target them by class? So instead of using `data-target="#text_2"` you could do `data-target=".text_2"`

Comment: They have already been assigned a class  though   <div id="text_2" class="hide_default" style="color: #26e08c">, But Ill try the way you suggested - thanks!

Comment: @CarinaThornval add the same class in HTML to all the elements that you want to "connect" with your *"button"*. Use that class inside the button data-target.

Comment: @CarinaThornval or add another line for that `"-2"` `$(this.dataset.target+"-2").removeClass('hidden')`, or use a more general selector like `$('[id^="'+ this.dataset.target +'"]')` which will target any `text_2****` elements ID